# NestJS onModuleInit lifecycle hook behaviour for async providers

Tags: nestjs

I am trying to initialize a `ConfigurationService` using the `onModuleInit` hook. Referring to the [NestJS Lifecycle Hooks Page](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events) I expect the hook to be called on module creation. This is not the case, however. Basically, I have this:

**ConfigurationService:**

```js
import { Injectable, OnModuleInit } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApplicationConfiguration } from './interfaces/application-configuration.interface';
import { ServerConfiguration } from './interfaces/server-configuration.interface';
import * as path from 'path';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigurationService implements OnModuleInit {
    private _configuration: ApplicationConfiguration;

    public async getServerConfigurationAsync(): Promise<ServerConfiguration> {
        await this.ensureConfigurationIsLoadedAsync();

        return new Promise<ServerConfiguration>((resolve, reject) => {
            const serverConfiguration = this._configuration.server;

            if (!serverConfiguration) {
                reject(new Error('Missing server configuration.'));
            }

            return resolve(serverConfiguration);
        });
    }

    private async ensureConfigurationIsLoadedAsync(): Promise<void> {
        if (!this._configuration) {
            this._configuration = await this.fetchAppConfigurationAsync();
        }
    }

    private fetchAppConfigurationAsync(): Promise<ApplicationConfiguration> {
        const configDir = process.env.CONFIG_DIR;

        let configurationPath: string;

        if (configDir) {
            configurationPath = path.resolve(`configuration/${configDir}/config.json`);
        }
        else {
            configurationPath = path.resolve('configuration/config.json');
        }

        return new Promise<ApplicationConfiguration>((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const configuration = require(configurationPath);

                const mappedConfig: ApplicationConfiguration = {
                    server: configuration.server
                };

                resolve(mappedConfig);
            }
            catch (error) {
                console.log(`Can't fetch configuration at ${configurationPath}.`);

                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }

    // public async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    //     console.log('ConfigurationService onModuleInit called.');

    //     await this.ensureConfigurationIsLoadedAsync();
    // }

    public  onModuleInit(): void {
        console.log('ConfigurationService onModuleInit called.');
    }
}
```

**Specific Async Provider:**

```js
export const SERVER_CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER: Provider = {
    provide: CONFIGURATION_TOKENS.SERVER_CONFIGURATION,
    useFactory: async (configurationService: ConfigurationService): Promise<ServerConfiguration> => {
        console.log('SERVER_CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER useFactory called.');

        return await configurationService.getServerConfigurationAsync();
    },
    inject: [ConfigurationService]
}
```

**Configuration Module:**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [
    ConfigurationService,
    SERVER_CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER
  ],
  exports: [
    SERVER_CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER
  ]
})
export class ConfigurationModule { 

  // public async onModuleInit(): Promise<void> {
    //     console.log('ConfigurationModule onModuleInit called.');
    // }
  public onModuleInit(): void {
        console.log('ConfigurationModule onModuleInit called.');
    }
    }
```

**And this is how I am trying to consume it:**

```js
@Controller('app')
export class AppController {
    private _serverConfig: ServerConfiguration;

    constructor(@Inject(CONFIGURATION_TOKENS.SERVER_CONFIGURATION) serverConfig: ServerConfiguration) {
        this._serverConfig = serverConfig;
    }

    @Get()
    public async getResult(): Promise<any> {
        return this._serverConfig;
    }
}
```

Now, the thing is I want to scrap the `await this.ensureConfigurationIsLoadedAsync();` call in the `getServerConfigurationAsync()` method and initialize the Configuration through the `onModuleInit` hook. However, when running the application, the hook gets called long after the `ConfigurationService` gets consumed by the async provider. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the hook be invoked before the service gets consumed? The documentation states:

> Called once the host module's dependencies have been resolved.

And

> For each module, after module initialization:

> await child controller & provider onModuleInit() methods

> await module onModuleInit() method

However, I also found this in the source code:

> nest/packages/core/nest-application.ts

```
public async init(): Promise<this> {
    this.applyOptions();
    await this.httpAdapter?.init();

    const useBodyParser =
      this.appOptions && this.appOptions.bodyParser !== false;
    useBodyParser && this.registerParserMiddleware();

    await this.registerModules();
    await this.registerRouter();
    await this.callInitHook();
    await this.registerRouterHooks();
    await this.callBootstrapHook();

    this.isInitialized = true;
    this.logger.log(MESSAGES.APPLICATION_READY);
    return this;
}
```

So I am not sure what to expect and if I get the lifecycle right. Here is my log when I start the Application:

```
Before app create
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
SERVER_CONFIGURATION_PROVIDER useFactory called.
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [InstanceLoader] ConfigurationModule dependencies initialized +10ms
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +1ms
After app create
before listen
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [RoutesResolver] AppController {/api/app}: +5ms
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/app, GET} route +4ms
ConfigurationService onModuleInit called.
ConfigurationModule onModuleInit called.
[Nest] 28132   - 10/05/2020, 4:12:38 PM   [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +2ms
after listen
Listening at port 5000.
```

Comment: ```the hook gets called long after the ConfigurationService gets consumed by the async provider. Am I missing something? Shouldn't the hook be invoked before the service gets consumed?```

What do you mean by "consume"? Instantiation and injection happen first. Then it cycles back and invokes onModuleInit.